# Unable to Web scrape a dynamic responsive table using python selenium using options from multiple dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** the contents of the table listed on the website (https://www.moneycontrol.com/fixed-income/bank_fd_main.php#data) bearing the filters of **Group - Cooperative Banks, Period - 2 < 3 yrs and Tax status - All** and load it into pandas dataframe. Despite trying hard, I am unable to execute the script bearing these 3 requirements.

I am unable to understand if there is a way to possibly pass all these arguments via **find_elements_by_xpath()** or any other similar function. I also tried to use **WebDriverWait()** so as to allow some time to load all the contents of the page, but despite doing so the executor returns me **NULLValueError** - thereby unable to locate the required elements.

Please help me to **scrape** the dynamic table along with above 3 requirements. Thanks in advance!!! Please find my attached code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/sidrocks/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com/fixed-income/bank_fd_main.php#data")

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='sel_banktype']/option[@value='Cooperative Banks']")[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='sel_period']/option[@value='2 < 3 yrs']")[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@name="tax_status"]/option[@value="All"]')[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('MT10')[0].click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "PA3 brd whbg")))

except TimeoutException:
    pass

soup = bsp(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

data = list()

table_data = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "PA3 MT10 brd whbg"}).find("table")

# To extract individual row elements from the html page
for j in table_data.findAll('tr'):
    row_data = j.findAll('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data]
    data.append(row)

head = data[1]
data = data[3:]

table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=head)

print(table)
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away, which is pretty much the opposite of what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is this filter:

> Group - Cooperative Banks, Period - 2 < 3 yrs and Tax status - All

then you don't really need the heavy guns of `selenium`. Actually, this can be done with pure `requests` and `pandas`.

Here's how:

```python
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

endpoint = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/fixed-income/bank_fd_main.php"

query = {
    "post_flag": True,
    "call_type": "best",
    "sel_banktype": "Cooperative Banks",
    "sel_int": 1,
    "sel_period": 8,
    "sel_amt": 1,
    "sel_cat": "G",
    "tax_status": "",
    "x": 22,
    "y": 14,
}

page = requests.post(endpoint, data=query).text
df = pd.read_html(page, flavor="bs4", skiprows=[0, 2])[-1]
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False))
```

Output:

```
-------------------------  -----------------  --------------  ----------------------------  ------------------  -------------  ----------  ---------
INSTITUTION                GROUP              INTEREST % p.a  period                        INVESTMENT (Rs)     Investor Type  tax status  nan
Bandhan Co-operative Bank  Cooperative Banks  6.15            2 years to less than 3 years  Less than Rs. 2 cr  General        Taxable     Calculate
-------------------------  -----------------  --------------  ----------------------------  ------------------  -------------  ----------  ---------
```

You can easily dump the `df` to `.csv` file, if you wish.

PS.

> It's *scrape* **not** *scrap*.

Comment: Thank you @baduker. This actually worked.